# How to create a table for a weak entity using microsoft sql server which contains a partial key?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, entity-relationship, database-schema

How to create a table for a weak entity using microsoft sql server ?

The weak entity contains a partial key, and it is denoted in the ER diagram using a dotted line.

My issue is, how to create a table to this weak entity including it's partial key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example:

First entity: `Book(BookId - PK, Titlle)`

Second entity (the weak entity): `Chapter(No, Title)` (at this point `Chapter.No` isn't a primary key because one or more books may have chapters with the same `No`).

In order to create the *weak* table I would add `BookId` to `Chapter` table and, also, I would create a compound unique key and a simple PK:

```
create table dbo.Chapter(

Id int identity primary key,

BookId int not null referenced dbo.Book(BookId),

No tinyint not null,

unique(BoolId, No),

Title nvarchar(100) not null

);
```

The reasons for defining a simple PK for `dbo.Chapter` are:

1) a compound PK could force me to define, also, compound FKs and

2) FK join elimination requires a simple FK.

Comment: Thank you. What is exactly meant by identity primary key? Is it because, the weak entity hasn't got any primary keys ?

Comment: References: [IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) columns. IDENTITY columns is SQL Server's solution for auto increment values. Thus, `dbo.Chapter.Id` is a [Surrogate key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key). Yep.